# How to unset Elasticsearch routing

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the shrink API and it requires you to move all shards to a single node.  After the shrink operation is completed I wish to have the shards on the original index reassigned though out the cluster.

So my question is how to I reverse this command?  I attempted to set _name to "*" but that did not work.

```
curl -s -XPUT "#{ES_HOST}:9200/#{BULK_INDEX}/_settings?pretty" -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": "shrink-node-1"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set it to null instead but you also need to remove the `settings` section since you're already hitting the `_settings` endpoint:

```
curl -s -XPUT "#{ES_HOST}:9200/#{BULK_INDEX}/_settings?pretty" -d '
{
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": null
}'
```